# C# Data Adapter Parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I've written some code to get some data out of my database. The `stored procedure` only uses the `ID` as the parameter, and uses that to filter results. I've run the `stored procedure` using the EXEC command in `SSMS` and it works. However, when I try and call it using the code at the bottom, it fails, saying that I have not provided the parameter. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{       
    try
    {
        DataTable dtBets = new DataTable("All Bets");
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("up_Select_all", sqlConnect))
        {
            sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = pCustomer.CustomerID;

            sqlDA.Fill(dtBets);
            return dtBets;
        }                        
    }

    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //catch code
    }
```

Comment: pCustomer is the object we're using. We've put a breakpoint on and it does pass a value. The sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters **does** have a value in there, as it claims the count is at 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have forgotten to tell the `DataAdapter` that it should call a `Stored-Procedure`:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("up_Select_all", sqlConnect))
{
    sqlDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = pCustomer.CustomerID;

    sqlDA.Fill(dtBets);
    return dtBets;
}
```