# SQL insert and update works in Toad but not in VB.NET code

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a web form aspx page for adding a new Client to the Client table using a stored procedure that has three mandatory parameters. This is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_NewClient]
       @ClientCode  VARCHAR (12)
     , @ClientName  VARCHAR (100)
     , @ClientPhone VARCHAR (20)
AS
INSERT INTO Client (
       ClientCode
     , ClientName
     , ClientPhone
     )
VALUES (
       @ClientCode
     , @ClientName
     , @ClientPhone
     )
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client]
     ( [ClientID]               INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
     , [ClientCode]             VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL
     , [ClientName]             VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
     , [ClientPhone]            VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
     )
ON [PRIMARY]
```

`ClientID` is referred to from the `ClientContact` table as its foreign key.

If I use the procedure like

```
exec proc_NewClient 'somecode','somename','5551212'
```

it works fine in Toad (although the insert will accept an empty string, which is puzzling). In the VB.NET code behind the aspx page, however, the code breaks here:

```
Dim conSTR As String = ""
conSTR = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim con As SqlConnection
con = New SqlConnection(conSTR)
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("proc_UpdateVendor", con)
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("proc_NewClient", con)
'    prepare da with parameters etc
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  '<-- code breaks here
```

with the error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"PrimayContact_FK". The conflict occurred in database "db", 
table "dbo.ClientContact", column 'ClientContactID'.
```

I don't understand this and have no idea how to debug it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This code worked a few weeks ago and I have changed nothing in the VB code except for error checking and comments. I have changed nothing in the stored procedure or the tables. There are two triggers on the ClientContact table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgClientContact_ins]
    ON [dbo].[ClientContact]
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ClientContact
       SET RecCreateDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
         , RecCreateUser = CURRENT_USER
      FROM ClientContact
     INNER JOIN inserted
        ON (ClientContact.ClientContactID = inserted.ClientContactID)
END
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgClientContact_upd]
    ON [dbo].[ClientContact]
    FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ClientContact
       SET RecModifyDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
         , RecModifyUser = CURRENT_USER
      FROM ClientContact
     INNER JOIN inserted
        ON (ClientContact.ClientContactID = inserted.ClientContactID)
END
```

Why there is no error on insert inside Toad but there is in VB.NET is confusing.

EDIT2: I have just found that the error is occurring on update as well as insert, which seems obvious given the triggers. Similar table etc.

EDIT3: Full table description of ClientContact

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientContact]
(   [ClientContactID]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
 , [ClientID]               INT          NOT NULL
 , [CliContactName]         VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
 , [CliContactPhone]        VARCHAR (20) NULL
 , [CliContactFax]          VARCHAR (20) NULL
 , [CliContactPager]        VARCHAR (20) NULL
 , [CliContactMobile]       VARCHAR (20) NULL
 , [CliContactEmergency]    VARCHAR (20) NULL
 , [CliContactPhoneExt]     VARCHAR (10) NULL
 , [CliContactFaxExt]       VARCHAR (10) NULL
 , [CliContactPagerExt]     VARCHAR (10) NULL
 , [CliContactMobileExt]    VARCHAR (10) NULL
 , [CliContactEmergencyExt] VARCHAR (10) NULL
 , [CliContactEmail]        VARCHAR (200)NULL
 , [RecTimestamp]           TIMESTAMP    NULL
 , [RecCreateDate]          DATETIME     NULL
 , [RecCreateUser]          VARCHAR (100)NULL
 , [RecModifyDate]          DATETIME     NULL
 , [RecModifyUser]          VARCHAR (100)NULL
 , [CliContactNotes]        VARCHAR (2000) NULL
 , PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    ([ClientContactID] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
        , FILLFACTOR = 90
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        , DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE)
    ON [PRIMARY]
, FOREIGN KEY ([ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([ClientID])
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Did you assign clientcontactid as an autonumber identity insert on?  Also an empty string != null.

Comment: The error refers to a table you do not otherwise mention: have you simplified for the question too much?

Comment: @JonH, ClientContactID is an autonumber but it's only triggered on insert into the ClientContact table; and agreed, null is not empty string. I just didn't expect it, since the field is mandatory in the table. Richard, nothing happens in the ClientContact table when inserting into the Client table. That's why I'm so confused here. I may have simplified too much, but I have no idea what else I can offer.

Comment: Do you even have a database called db?

Comment: This will be really simple to fix when you share enough of the problem. Is there a trigger on your contact table? What is the structure of ClientContact? That table isn't part of your post but is the table that is being inserted to.

Comment: @JonH I named it db in the code above, it is different in my code. I just wanted to make it generic here. Sean, I did find two triggers on the ClientContact table, but the procedure works fine from inside Toad with the exact parameters that I send in the VB code. This code worked a few weeks ago and I have changed nothing in the VB code except for error checking and comments. I'll make a note of this in an edit to my question.

Comment: @SeanLange the insert is into the Client table, not the ClientContact table.

Comment: But what is the foreign key definition for PrimayContact_FK? There is something in your trigger that is causing the foreign key violation but we don't know what the foreign key definition is.

Comment: I found the definition: `FOREIGN KEY ([ClientPrimaryContact]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ClientContact] ([ClientContactID])` and it has to do with assigning a Primary Contact to this Client in the web page. But the error is in the web page but not in Toad. I didn't pass in a Primary Contact ID in Toad, so why in the page?

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the parameters in the procedure

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("proc_UpdateVendor", con)
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCode", "myvalue")
MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myparameter2", "myvalue2")
'add the others
da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I left out a page of code to simplify my question. My comment "add the others" refers to my adding the parameters. But thanks, I appreciate the answer. I'll add the code if you think I should, but that will make my question HUGE.

Comment: @pixelmeow yeah you should put your whole code it would help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the business rule. There is no data to pass for the mandatory field `ClientContactID` because, as a new client, there is no contact in the `ClientContact` table.

Thank you all for your help, your answers and comments definitely helped me work through this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set your SelectCommand type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566980/c-sharp-data-adapter-parameters) for how to set it up.

Comment: Could you update the code snippet to show that? There may be a problem somewhere else and you're seeing a bogus error...

Comment: Done. Let me know if I need to add more.

Comment: Could you post the ClientContact definition? Are you trying to insert a duplicate in ClientContact that isn't allowed?

Comment: I've posted the code, but I'm not inserting anything into the ClientContact table. It's updating that table when I insert/update into Client, marking one of the ClientContact records as the Prime Contact for that Client.